# Kernel modules for iptables ftp forward

Tags: iptables, ftp, port-forwarding

I have two ARM devices connected to each other with TCP/IP, one of them is connected to my network, on the other one is FTP server.
I'm trying to set up port forwarding to ftp using conntrack and helper:

```
## raw
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j CT --helper ftp
## filter
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.201.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
## nat
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.201.1:21
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE

# cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper
0
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1

# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
nf_nat_ftp              1839  0
nf_conntrack_ftp        6534  2 nf_nat_ftp
xt_CT                   3205  1
iptable_raw             1510  1
xt_conntrack            2886  0
iptable_filter          1808  1
ipt_MASQUERADE          1102  1
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4     2734  1 ipt_MASQUERADE
xt_nat                  1671  1
xt_tcpudp               2137  3
iptable_nat             1803  1
nf_conntrack_ipv4       6580  2
nf_defrag_ipv4          1435  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
nf_nat_ipv4             5261  1 iptable_nat
nf_nat                 15612  4 xt_nat,nf_nat_ftp,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,nf_nat_ipv4
nf_conntrack           76225  8 nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_nat_ftp,xt_CT,nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4,xt_conntrack,nf_nat_ipv4,nf_nat
ip_tables              11523  3 iptable_filter,iptable_raw,iptable_nat
x_tables               18629  8 xt_nat,ip_tables,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,iptable_raw,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_CT,xt_conntrack
```

This setup works on desktop systems, but doesn't work on my compilation of linux (ti-linux-kernel 4.9.50)

My question is: are there any modules I'm missing here?